# Order wordpress gallery images by filename

Tags: wordpress, image, gallery, wordpress-shortcode

I have many folders with images for creating Wordpress galleries. Image names are numbered such as (1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.). I want wordpress gallery show images by file name. I have found suggestion to use ' orderby="title" ' but it doesnt help. What can i do?

Thanks.

Comment: please post some code along, otherwise no one here will be able to help you.

Comment: There is no actual code. The thing is I am uploading images with numbered names from say 1.jpg to 50.jpg. Wordpress doesn't show them by exact order.

Comment: @funkysoul Please review my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. As I mentioned before my files were named as " 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and etc. ". Wordpress orderby="title" function ordered the images in the following order " 1.jpg, 10.jpg, 11.jpg, 12.jpg and etc. "

I wanted wordrpess to order files by natural order like 1, ...9, 10, 11 etc.

So I have changed image names format as following "01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg ..." and it solved my problem.

Note: You have to delete image metadata ( title data. After this procedure Wordpress will read image titles from file names.